# Django queryset doesn't update when filtered

Tags: python, django

Following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QFs6qgvyTC4) (starting at 7'05), I'm trying to implement a facet filter based navigation.

Here's my code:

##### models.py

```
class ObjetArchi(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(
        primary_key=True,
        )  
    materiau = models.ForeignKey(
        'Materiau',
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        related_name='objets_archi',
        blank=True,
        null=True
        )

class Materiau(models.Model);
    id = models.AutoField(
        primary_key=True
        )
    nom = models.CharField(
        max_length=125,
        blank=True,
        null=True
        )
```

##### views.py

```
class NoticesListView(ListView):
    model = ObjetArchi
    template_name = 'notices/index.html'
    context_object_name = 'liste_notices'
    paginate_by = 20

    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = super().get_queryset()
        materiau = self.request.GET.get('materiau__nom')
        if materiau:
            qs = qs.filter(type=materiau)
        return qs

    def get_context_data(self, **kws):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kws)
        context['materiaux'] = (
            self.get_queryset()
            .values('materiau__nom')
            .annotate(count=Count('id'))
        )
        return context
```

##### urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.NoticesListView.as_view(), name='notices_list'),
]
```

#### notices/index.html

```
{% for materiau in materiaux %}
    <ul>
        <a href="?materiau={{ materiau.materiau__nom }}">
        {{ materiau.materiau__nom }} ({{ materiau.count }})
    </ul>
{% endfor %}

{% if liste_notices %}
    <ul>
    {% for notice in liste_notices %}
        <li><a href="{% url 'notices:detail' notice.id %}">{{ notice.titre }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% else %}
    <p>Aucune notice n'est accessible.</p>
{% endif %}
```

The facet shows up with the expected materiau__nom and count, but the queryset doesn't update when I click on the filter categories. Is there any visible error in the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is solved this way:

view.py

```
def get_queryset(self):
  qs = super().get_queryset()
  materiau = self.request.GET.get('materiau')
  if materiau:
      qs = qs.filter(materiau__nom=materiau)
  return qs
```

index.html

```
{% for materiau in materiaux %}
    <ul>
        <a href="?materiau={{ materiau.materiau__nom }}">
        {{ materiau.materiau__nom }} ({{ materiau.count }})
    </ul>
{% endfor %}
```